# Rsync producing folders with wrong permissions

Tags: windows-xp, osx-lion, rsync, file-permissions, cwrsync

I'm rsyncing content from my Windows XP box to an OS X Lion box, and some of the folders have the wrong permission.

```
> rsync -rtvz --del "/cygdrive/c/rsync_20101220/" "agrimm@[redacted]:'/Users/agrimm/external/daiichi/Top level files/rsync_20101220'"
[lot of listing of files skipped. More logging than buffer, so I don't know if any logging messages were lost]
sent 2439672264 bytes  received 1444272 bytes  795800.01 bytes/sec
total size is 22869261932  speedup is 9.37
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1042) [sender=3.0.7]
```

On the OS X box, this is what I get permission-wise:

```
~ agrimm$ cd external/daiichi/
daiichi agrimm$ ls -ltra
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   6 agrimm  staff  204 Aug 24  2011 Thunderbird
drwxr-xr-x   6 agrimm  staff  204 Jul  4 09:21 FinePrint files
drwxr-xr-x   4 agrimm  staff  136 Jul 10 13:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  17 agrimm  staff  578 Jul 11 10:50 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x   6 agrimm  staff  204 Jul 11 11:22 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 agrimm  staff  102 Jul 11 11:25 Top level files
daiichi agrimm$ cd Top\ level\ files/
Top level files agrimm$ ls -ltra
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 agrimm  staff  170 Aug 18  2011 rsync_20101220
drwxr-xr-x  6 agrimm  staff  204 Jul 11 11:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 agrimm  staff  102 Jul 11 11:25 .
Top level files agrimm$ cd rsync_20101220/
rsync_20101220 agrimm$ ls -ltra
total 0
d-wx------   4 agrimm  staff  136 Dec  4  2009 Desktop
d-wx------  13 agrimm  staff  442 Apr  5  2011 gitrepos
drwxr-xr-x   5 agrimm  staff  170 Aug 18  2011 .
drwx------   7 agrimm  staff  238 Aug 18  2011 code
drwxr-xr-x   3 agrimm  staff  102 Jul 11 11:25 ..
rsync_20101220 agrimm$ ls Desktop/
ls: : Permission denied
rsync_20101220 agrimm$ ls gitrepos/
ls: : Permission denied
rsync_20101220 agrimm$ ls -ltr code/
total 0
d-wx------   3 agrimm  staff  102 Jan 20  2010 temporary_development
d-wx------   3 agrimm  staff  102 Dec  2  2010 merging
d-wx------   3 agrimm  staff  102 Dec 21  2010 inactive
d-wx------   5 agrimm  staff  170 Jul  4  2011 sandbox
d-wx------  19 agrimm  staff  646 Aug 24  2011 hiv_recombination
rsync_20101220 agrimm$ ls -R code/
hiv_recombination       inactive                merging                 sandbox                 temporary_development

code//hiv_recombination:
ls: hiv_recombination: Permission denied

code//inactive:
ls: inactive: Permission denied

code//merging:
ls: merging: Permission denied

code//sandbox:
ls: sandbox: Permission denied

code//temporary_development:
ls: temporary_development: Permission denied
rsync_20101220 agrimm$
```

The permissions and users of the files look consistent on the Windows box. From within git bash:

```
A.Grimm@AGRIMM-MED /c/rsync_20101220
$ ls -ltra
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 A.Grimm  Administ        0 Dec  4  2009 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x   13 A.Grimm  Administ        0 Apr  5  2011 gitrepos
drwxr-xr-x    5 A.Grimm  Administ        0 Aug 18  2011 .
drwxr-xr-x    7 A.Grimm  Administ        0 Aug 18  2011 code
drwxr-xr-x   26 A.Grimm  Administ        0 Jul 11 12:55 ..
```

Why would the permissions be wrong in some circumstances, but not in others? Should I just delete "rsync_20101220" on the OS X box and do it again with -p added to the rsync command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find using `-p` fixed things. Instead, I manually created empty versions of the problem directories, and then rsynced.